# How I can set angle between edge in given code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to change angle between edge but unable to do it. Code is given below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[sibling distance=25em,
    every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center, 
        top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
    ]
    \node {Body\\ Temperature}
    child { node {Non\\Mammal} edge from parent [->] node [left] {Cold}}
    child { node {Give\\ Birth} edge from parent [->] node [right] {Warm}
        child { node {Mammal}edge from parent [->] node [left] {Yes}}
        child { node {Non \\ Mammal} edge from parent [->] node [right] {No}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is in general a good idea to extend the code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately your code doesn't compile. Please add the missing lines. Thank you

Comment: You can format your code by highlighting it with your mouse, and then clicking the `{}` icon that appears above the question box.  This makes it much easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want is the following (but I am not sure which angle you actually want to change, maybe you can add some more information to your question about this):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        sibling distance=25em,
        every node/.style={
            shape=rectangle, 
            rounded corners, 
            draw, 
            align=center, 
            top color=white, 
            bottom color=blue!20
        },
    ]
    \node {Body \\ Temperature}
        child { node {Non \\ Mammal} edge from parent [->] node {Cold} }
        child { node {Give \\ Birth} 
            child { node {Mammal} edge from parent [->] node {Yes} }
            child { node {Non \\ Mammal} edge from parent [->] node {No} } 
            edge from parent [->] node {Warm}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `edge from parent` part should be placed after defining the `child`ren, especially if you add nodes that are to be placed on the edges (see [the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-trees#sec-21.6) for another example). For nicer positioning, I would remove the `right` or `left` option from the nodes that are placed on the edges.

To change the angle in such a basic tree (that is, a Ti*k*Z tree that does not use any additional library), you can change the angle of the edges using the `sibling distance` and/or `level distance` options that you can not only add to the whole tree, but also to specific `child`ren. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        sibling distance=25em,
        every node/.style={
            shape=rectangle, 
            rounded corners, 
            draw, 
            align=center, 
            top color=white, 
            bottom color=blue!20
        },
    ]
    \node {Body \\ Temperature}
        child { node {Non \\ Mammal} edge from parent [->] node {Cold} }
        child { node {Give \\ Birth} 
            child [sibling distance=5em] { node {Mammal} edge from parent [->] node {Yes} }
            child [level distance=10em] { node {Non \\ Mammal} edge from parent [->] node {No} } 
            edge from parent [->] node {Warm}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `forest`, which allows you to set the angle for the entire tree using `calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=<angle>`. The angle (set to 60 in the example below) is the angle between the edge and a vertical line from the parent. You can adjust `l sep` to change the vertical spacing between nodes.

Note that `\forestset` rather than `\tikzset` is needed for the main nodes because `forest` vertically aligns nodes differently from `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{nodestyle/.style={rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}}
\tikzset{labelstyle/.style={midway, rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=yellow!20}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    nodestyle,
    l sep=1.2cm,
    edge={->},
    calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=60
}
[Body\\Temperature
    [Non\\Mammal, edge label={node[labelstyle]{Cold}}]
    [Give\\Birth, edge label={node[labelstyle]{Warm}}
        [Non\\Mammal, base=top, edge label={node[labelstyle]{No}}]
        [Mammal, edge label={node[labelstyle]{Yes}}]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```